# How to open a PhoneGap application from an email link

Tags: iphone, ios, email, cordova

I am working on a application which will send a verification email to given email address. And on clicking the verification link in email I need to launch my application.

Is there any way by which I can open the iOS application from verification link.

Answer (score 1):

setting your app's unique URL Scheme  &  set link to your app's URL Scheme in safari's web page

& you can handle the parameters from the safari too

http://yashesh87.wordpress.com/2012/01/03/open-your-iphone-app-from-safari-browser-in-iphone-using-url-schemes/